# Downgrading TypeScript back to 0.8.3

Tags: typescript

Is there a way i can uninstall TypeScript 0.9 from my visual studio and get back to 0.8.3?
I have made a huge mistake by upgrading. It basically killed all my code.

Comment: My question was going to be "Where do I download 0.8.3?" the MS download page hides the previous releases (see @Mark Verrey's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Uninstall whatever version you have
2. Download the version you would like to have
3. Install it

Comment: +1 for the detailed instructions. Of course, you'll still need to fix your code eventually!

Comment: This just in - switch between different versions using Diullei's switching tool: https://npmjs.org/package/multi-typescript

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing your issue was with where to find the old version, which took me quite a while.

- Go to the regular download site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790
- Expand "Details"
- Under "Releases," select the version you want.

It's not very deep in the page hierarchy, yet it's frustratingly hard to find.